# Hibernate: Collection does not repopulate after save of Many-to-Many join

Tags: hibernate, collections, many-to-many

I just need to figure out why my collection of Roles would not populate member properties after save (add). I have two tables, User and Role, and the join table UserRole.

```
public class User implements Serializable {
private int id;
@NotBlank(message = "{User.userName.notBlank}")
@AlphaNumeric(message = "{User.userName.alphaNumeric}")
private String name;
@NotBlank(message = "{User.password.notBlank}")
@AlphaNumeric(message = "{User.password.alphaNumeric}")
private String password;
private boolean enabled;
private boolean deleteSafe; 
@NotEmpty(message="{User.roles.notEmpty}")

private Set<Role> roles; <-- this is my problem
```

And here is my Hibernate XML mapping

```
<class name="User">
    <id name="id">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="name"></property>
    <property name="password"></property>
    <set name="roles" table="UserRoles" lazy="false">
        <key column="userId"></key>
        <many-to-many column="roleId" class="Role"></many-to-many>
    </set>
</class>
```

And here is the simple Role class

```
public class Role implements Serializable {
private int id; 
private String authority;
private String name;
```

My UserRole table consists only of two columns, userId which maps to the id of User, and roleId, which maps to the id in Role.

I pass a User object with name, password, and a set of Roles.  Each Role in this list only has the id populated.  The UserRole table gets saved properly, but I want that after saving, the Set in my User object will have the authority and name attributes populated.

Those properties are populated in a normal 'get' User using the same mapping, I was hoping it will do the same after it does a 'save'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hibernate won't do that. You basicly have a broken model here and hibernate can not distinguish between a Role with password set to null and a dummy Role which you want it to populate. If you just want to assign Roles with known ids to the newly created User then use session.load().

```
for(long roleId : roleIds)
{
    newUser.getRoles().add(session.load(Role.class, roleId));
}
```

the Roles returned by session.Load are proxies which do not generate a roundtrip until they are accessed.

Update: if you know you need the roles later then eager loading them would be better

```
for(Role role : session.CreateCriteria(Role.class).add(Expression.in("id", roleIds)).list())
{
    newUser.getRoles().add(role);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, might as well do it this way.